# Validation message disappears and form is submitted

Tags: model-view-controller

Here is my validation message.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name, "", new { id = "valName" })
```

I assigned the value for the Id using the below jquery

```
$('#valName').html('new content');
```

but when clicking the submit button the validation message disappears and form is submitted.

how to keep the validation message when button is clicked ?

Comment: Please add relevant tags to your question to ensure it is visible.

Comment: Why are you setting the text of the span element generated by `ValidationMessageFor()` - that is the responsibility of  `jquery.validate.js` (which is does when you submit) What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: couple questions: does your form have "@Html.ValidationSummary(true" ?

Comment: in web.config: <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> ???

Answer (score 0):

You must include the following scripts in the view:

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```